Xcode doesn't match the entitlement com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier
Hi I'm also having similar problem with this issue. I found that the Apple website said to "Update your entitlements plist with the full KVS value in your provisioning profile." https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/transfer-an-app/overview-of-app-transfer But they don't provide any details on how to do it, I have reached out to Apple but no replies whatsoever.
Has anyone found a solution? In the comments, Isuru suggests that

Actually there's no way to keep Key-value storage when we change Application identifier. So I removed Key-value storage option or else we can use different identifier. However it will remove previous stored Key-value storage related to app Blockquote

If we unchecked Key-value storage, will the new entitlement automatically replace the old one for existing users?
Mrzezk suggests simply replacing the team ID. Since I'm new to Xcode, can someone explain how to change an entitlement?
